# Executing a basic shell command in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

At a very early stage of learning the language, and working through the ElixirSips series of videos. I keep hitting stuff that's been slightly obseleted by language changes. Trying to wrap my head around this, and Google/Github issue trackers/SO trawling is getting me nowhere useful. I have this very basic module, which should just run a shell command:

```
defmodule QuickieSynth.Sound do
  def command(note) do
    "play -qn synth 2 pluck #{note}"
  end

  def play(note) do
    note |> command |> System.cmd
  end
end
```

However, when this file is compiled and the tests run, I get an argument error; fair enough - System.cmd/1 seems to no longer be part of the standard lib.

System.cmd/3 *is* in the standard lib, and reading the docs indicated the options are, well, optional. So I pass empty args `note |> command |> System.cmd([])`, and what I get back is `erlang: :enoent`: again after reading the docs a bit more carefully, fair enough.

So I try to use Erlang's `:os.cmd/1`, so `note |> command |> :os.cmd`, and I get `(FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :os.validate/1`. And I am now stuck.

Comment: I write another function to make that tutorial work on recent versions of Elixir: `def run(full_cmd) do
    [cmd| args] = String.split(full_cmd, " ")

    System.cmd(cmd, args)
  end`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`System.cmd/3` seems to accept the arguments to the command as a list and is not happy when you try to sneak in arguments in the command name. For example `System.cmd("ls", ["-al"])` works, while `System.cmd("ls -al", [])` does not. So in your case you'll probably need something like:

```
System.cmd("play", ["-qn", "synth", "2", "pluck", note])
```

What in fact happens underneath is `System.cmd/3` calls `:os.find_executable/1` with its first argument, which works just fine for something like `ls` but returns false for `ls -al`.

If you decide to go the pure erlang route, then the call expects a char list instead of a binary, so you need something like the following:

```
"ls -al" |> String.to_char_list |> :os.cmd
```

Comment: Ah, that makes complete sense. I'll want to build in options anyway, so it was just that first basic step that was tripping me up; I can't pipe it in the way I was trying to. BTW, any idea why the Erlang call won't work (:os.cmd)?

Comment: Added that to the answer